# Prove $x \notin x$ without regularity?

Tags: set-theory

In $\mathsf{ZF}$, can we prove that no set is an element of itself without using regularity? My guess is that it is not possible, but I have no idea how to prove this.

Comment: Its not possible, but $\mathrm{ZFC}$ cannot prove that its not possible - you need a little bit more power. I suspect that $\mathrm{ZFC}+\mathrm{Con}(\mathrm{ZFC})$ can prove that its impossible.

Comment: Does that mean both (ZF without Regularity + $\exists x (x \in x)$) and (ZF without Regularity + $\neg \exists x (x \in x)$) are consistent?

Comment: @MathStudent020: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *Quine atom* is a solution to $x=\{x\}$. Working within ZFC we can construct a *class model* of ZFC${}-{}$Regularity${}+{}$"there exist $\aleph_0$ Quine atoms", by defining the cumulative hierarchy on top of a set of postulated atoms:

Let $A = \{0\}\times \mathbb N $ and define by transfinite induction
$$ U_\alpha = A \cup \{1\} \times \Big[ \mathcal P(\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha} U_\beta ) \setminus \{ \{a\} \mid a\in A\}\Big]$$
and then let
$$ \mathbf U = \bigcup_{\alpha\in\mathbf{ON}} U_\alpha $$
Further define the relation $\tilde \in $ by
$$ x \mathop{\tilde\in} y \iff \begin{cases} x=y & \text{if }y=\langle 0,z\rangle \\ x\in z & \text{if }y=\langle 1,z\rangle \end{cases} $$

Then, jumping to the metalevel, we can see that $(\mathbf U,\tilde\in)$ is a model for every axiom of ZFC except for Regularity, and that each $\langle 0,n\rangle\in\mathbf U$ is a Quine atom.

Therefore, if ZFC is consistent, then ZFC $-$ Regularity does not prove $x\notin x$.